# How can I run my systemd service with a SCHED_DEADLINE scheduling policy?

Tags: systemd, scheduling

I want to run my systemd service with a `SCHED_DEADLINE` scheduling policy.

I already have this with

```
chrt -d --sched-runtime 1000000 --sched-deadline 5000000 --sched-period 5000000 -p 0 <PID>
```

However this is a service and I don't want to apply this command manually.

I found that in my service config I can change `CPUSchedulingPolicy` and `CPUSchedulingPriority`, but according to [this manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) the value

> Takes one of other, batch, idle, fifo or rr

Plus I need to define runtime, deadline, period values somewhere.
So, is there any way to do that properly? I tried to put the `chrt` command in the `ExecStart` section, however thats doesn't work and I think it's not the best way

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10034). So is there any other way to do that properly?

Comment: I don't think `SCHED_DEADLINE` is supported.  `ExecStartPost=chrt -d ... -p 0 $MAINPID` might be your answer.  Just make sure `RestrictRealtime=off` is set (or at least, not explicitly `=on`).

Comment: Also please check the error message, i.e. shown in `systemctl status your-unit-here`, and that you are running as root :-).  Not sure why it would be worth using `ExecStartPost=` though?

Comment: According to [https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) NOTES, SCHED_DEADLINE is settable only via sched_setattr(2). When I check the latest systemd sources for sched_setattr(2), I don't see any references in the code, so SCHED_DEADLINE isn't supported. So, probably you can do the scheduling policy update of your service in a follow up service (After=<service-that-needs-policy-update>) using chrt(1).

Comment: @sourcejedi with systemctl I can run my service with rt scheduling even without root. My service must work without root. 

Using ExecStartPost doesn’t work with really strange error message. It’s like my program arguments loosing somewere. Still working on it

Comment: regarding permissions then I guess this involves using `ExecStartPost=+chrt ...`. (man systemd.service, "Table 1. Special executable prefixes")